# Column value must exist in non primary column of another table

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have two tables:

TABLE_1

```
ID     AGE_T1     NAME
1       5         A
2      23         B
3       5         C
4       9         D
```

TABLE_2

```
AGE_T2     FREQUENCY
5           2
9           1
23          1
```

How can I ensure that a `AGE_T2` value must be one of the values of `AGE_T1` (non-unique column of `TABLE_1`)? Need to mention that both `TABLE_1` and `TABLE_2` are physical tables (not any logical structure as `VIEW`).

Note: If `AGE_T1` were a primary key then *a foreign key constraint* would be enough for `AGE_T2`. I also have a plan to use `INSERT TRIGGER` if there is no better solution.

Comment: What is the purpose of `table_2`?  It appears that it is just an aggregate table.  If that is the case, assuming you really need a materialized object rather than simply creating a view, you're likely better off creating that as a fast-refreshable materialized view that Oracle maintains rather than a separate table that your application maintains that tries to enforce a pseudo foreign key.

Comment: Thanks for advice, BUT I need a normal physical table, not any kind of logical structure

Comment: Can you explain why?  In particular, why would it matter if this was a materialized view that Oracle maintains vs. a table that you maintain?  Do you want the ability to force the two tables to be out of sync?

Comment: @JustinCave Actually its not a aggregate/summary table. Real scenario is little bit bigger to share thats why I have mentioned the part what I need. Just a bit I can tell you that, may be ``Table_1`` has thousand of rows and hundred kind of ages, but I need to insert some of ages at ``Table_2`` depends on some  point of time. I hope I depict the scenario clear.

Comment: If you use a materialized view, your data will always be consistent and it will work in a multi-user system.  If you build your own table, you'd need triggers.  You'd need triggers when rows are deleted or updated in `1` and when they are inserted or updated in `2`.  Those triggers will not, realistically, work in a multi-user environment unless you implement some sort of serialization mechanism that will likely have a dramatic impact on the scalability of your application.  I would not advise going down the trigger path.

Comment: Only check constraint can achieve that but check constraints are not dynamic enough for your scenario because in Oracle they can not contain UDFs or sub queries. So a trigger or an ETL job seems to be your only work around.

Comment: I support @JustinCave and I think if you give it some thought it will make more sense to create a materialized view in a way that fits your needs.

Comment: @JustinCave Can I update column of materialized view manually just like a physical table or its read-only(sorry I dont know about materialized view)

Comment: If you want Oracle to maintain it, the materialized view would only change when `table1` (or some other table) changed.  If `age` is the key in `table2`, you could potentially create an additional table `table3` that is a child of `table2` and has whatever additional data you want to maintain.  Whether that is a reasonable solution really depends on your specific problem.

Comment: @JustinCave thanks for your comment, it seems to answer for me. Is MTO answer same as your comment?

Comment: It's a a similar approach but a bit different.  There are a number of different approaches depending on the specifics of what you are trying to model.

Comment: @JustinCave Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a materialized view to contain only the distinct ages in `TABLE_1`:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON TABLE_1
   WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID(AGE_T1)
   INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TABLE_1_MV
   BUILD IMMEDIATE
   REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
   AS SELECT DISTINCT AGE_T1
      FROM   TABLE_1;

ALTER TABLE TABLE_1_MV ADD CONSTRAINT t1_mv__age_t1__pk PRIMARY KEY ( AGE_T1 );
```

Then you can add a `FOREIGN KEY` on `TABLE_2` referencing this as the primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_2 ADD CONSTRAINT t2__age__fk FOREIGN KEY ( AGE_T2 )
  REFERENCES TABLE_1_MV ( AGE_T1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. **Not tested.**

It's also based on a materialized view; the MV must refresh on commit as in MT0's solution. Let the MV select only rows that violate your lookup condition - and let the MV have a check condition that always evaluates to FALSE, so that it will always reject the insert/update/delete if your original lookup condition is violated. You can make the "always false" constraint deferrable if needed.

This way you will only need one MV, and you won't need to maintain anything.

```
create materialized view TABLE_2_MV
   build immediate
   refresh fast on commit
   as select age_t2
      from   table_2
      where  age_t2 not in (select age_t1 from table_1);
alter table TABLE_2_MV add constraint t2_mv_chk (0 != 0);
```

Good luck!